# KMP Library gradle allTests fails due to jsNpm configuration

Tags: kotlin, circleci, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, circleci-2.0

I am creating a **Kotlin Multiplatform library**

The **CircleCI** build process fails because of this error message during testing:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':lib:jsPackageJson'.
> Cannot add a configuration with name 'jsNpm' as a configuration with that name already exists.
```

However the code works fine, testing runs flawless locally.

I really have no idea what it is or how I could fix it.

Unfortunately, there is still very little documentation on Kotlin Multiplatform as it is an experimental feature

My configuration is as follows:

Structure:

```
root
|-.circleci
   |-config.yml
|-build.gradle.kts
|-settings.gradle.kts
|-lib
   |-build.gradle.kts
```

***settings.gradle.kts***

```
rootProject.name = "library"

include(":lib")
enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")
```

***root build.gradle.kts***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        addRepos()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(ClassPaths.AndroidGradleBuildTools)
        classpath(ClassPaths.KotlinGradlePlugin)
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        addRepos()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
        }
    }
}
```

***src build.gradle.kts***

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("maven-publish")
}
group = "de.datlag"
version = Versions.releaseVersion

android {
    compileSdkVersion = Versions.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion = Versions.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode = Versions.releaseVersionCode
        versionName = Versions.releaseVersion
    }

    buildTypes {
        val debug by getting {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
            isShrinkResources = false
        }

        val release by getting {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = false
            isShrinkResources = false
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = Versions.java
        targetCompatibility = Versions.java
    }
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = Versions.java.toString()
        }
    }
    js {
        browser()
        nodejs()
    }
    android {
        publishAllLibraryVariants()
    }
    val hostOs = System.getProperty("os.name")
    val isMingwX64 = hostOs.startsWith("Windows")
    val nativeTarget = when {
        hostOs == "Mac OS X" -> macosX64("native")
        hostOs == "Linux" -> linuxX64("native")
        isMingwX64 -> mingwX64("native")
        else -> throw GradleException("Host OS is not supported in Kotlin/Native.")
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }
        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }
        val nativeMain by getting { }
        val nativeTest by getting { }
    }
}
```

***CircleCI config.yml***

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk

    working_directory: ~/repo

    environment:
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
      TERM: dumb
      CHROME_BIN: /usr/lib/chromium/chrome

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle.kts" }}
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run:
          name: Update
          command: sudo apt-get update

      - run:
          name: Install C-Bridge tool
          command: sudo apt-get install -y libncurses5

      - run: gradle dependencies

      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.gradle
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "build.gradle.kts" }}

      - run: gradle cleanAllTests
      - run: gradle allTests
```

Comment: The problem is not solved, but it seems that the problem is with CircleCI.
No problems in Github Actions (multiple platform tests set up)
I will stay with Github Actions now, but if someone has a solution it could of course be useful for other users